# Restart Game jQuery Function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a [jQuery Based Memory Game](http://www.slashc.com/codecanyon/jquery_memory_game/index.html) on my site. You can restart the game at anytime you like. Works great. Now I finish a game then I hit Play Again. If I hit restart it no longer works. Why and How do I fix it?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/ZXMUB/9/).

***JS:***

```
// this script shows how you can get info about the game
    var game = jQuery('div.slashc-memory-game'); // get the game
    var info = jQuery('p#info').find('span'); // get the info box
    var restart = jQuery('a#restart').css('visibility', 'visible'); // get the play again link
    var playAgain = jQuery('a#play-again').css('visibility', 'hidden'); // get the play again link
    // format time like hh:mm:ss
    var formatTime = function(s)
    {
        var h = parseInt(s / 3600), m = parseInt((s - h * 3600) / 60); s = s % 60;
        return (h < 10 ? '0' + h : h) + ':' + (m < 10 ? '0' + m : m) + ':' + (s < 10 ? '0' + s : s);
    }
    // listen for game 'done' event 
    game.bind('done', function(e)
    {
        // show basic stats
        var stats = game.slashcMemoryGame('getStats');
        info.html('Success ! Number of clicks : ' + stats.numClicks + ', elapsed time : ' + formatTime(parseInt(stats.time / 1000)) + '.');
        playAgain.css('visibility', 'visible'); // show link
        restart.css('visibility', 'hidden'); // show link
    });
            // Restart action
    restart.click(function(e)
    {
        game.slashcMemoryGame('restart'); // restart game
    });
    // play again action
    playAgain.click(function(e)
    {
        playAgain.css('visibility', 'hidden'); // hide link
        info.html('Memory Game, click to reveal images. <a id="restart" href="#">Restart</a>'); // reset text
        game.slashcMemoryGame('restart'); // restart game
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

***HTML:***

```
<p id="info"><span>Memory Game, click to reveal images. <a id="restart" href="#">Restart</a></span> <a id="play-again" href="#">Play Again</a></p>
```

Comment: this what i get in firebug console `missing } after function body`

Comment: I ran your fiddle (after corretcting the same issues as in your previous question, uncomment game var and removing closing script tag) and it still works fine. I can play the game, and after i finished i get the link to play again. The game keeps working after i hit play again. All seems to be working just fine for me (Chrome on Win) http://jsfiddle.net/ZXMUB/7/

Comment: @PeterVR - I gave the wrong fiddle link, my bad (New link in question). After you hit Play Again the game resets then you hit Restart the game does not restart. Note: Restart works before finishing the first time.

Comment: @Lynda still works, even 3'rd time ... I won't play until tomorrow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're replacing the `#restart` element whenever you click `#play-again` at this line:

```
info.html('Memory Game, click to reveal images. <a id="restart" href="#">Restart</a>');
```

This means the click handler for the `#restart` element is no longer attached to the new element.

You should attach the handler to an ancestor element which is always present in the DOM using a *delegated* event handler [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
info.on('click', '#restart', function(e)
{
    game.slashcMemoryGame('restart'); // restart game
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXMUB/12/)

I replaced the `#restart` element's directly-bound event handler with a delegated event handler. Here's the reference for an extra read: [Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). Basically, you can only bind event handlers to elements currently in the DOM, and:

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.